# WEB API service in layered approach

Tags: service, hosting, asp.net-web-api

First I'm new to WEB API. 
I would like to know when a ASP.NET MVC 4 web application is the user interface, then I need to use another  MVC 4 web application for hosting the WEB API, which is to host the business logic? Excuse me for my bad English.

EDIT:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350488/A-simple-POC-using-ASP-NET-Web-API-Entity-Framewor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the api should be a WCF web service in my opinion

Comment: That's a bit of a blanket statement when you don't know what the web api is being proposed to be used for. WCF is heavy if you are just using it to handle some AJAX events from a single application - that was why the WebAPI was created.

Comment: looks like from the comment below, that's what he wanted

Answer (score 0):

If the web api is being used for ajax calls from the browser then it should be in the same application as the web pages that call it.

What exactly are you using the WebAPI for?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I want to use it like WCF separate the UI from business layer and data access layer to serve different user interface and deploy them different servers.